# Can't Copy Files With Multiple Extensions with FOR /R

Tags: batch-file

I can't get two extensions in the same line to work with the entire `for /r`.

I have a huge folder with `.log`, `.html` and `.js` and I tried to basically use the `for /r` thing to `copy` `.log` and `.js` in the same line. Once I succeeded, but recently lost the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

I tried all of these ways to list multiple extensions

```
(*.log;*.js)
(*.log,*.js)
(*.log),(*.js)
(*.log);(*.js)
```

but am still not sure what the correct syntax is in something like the following:

```
for /r "d:\temp" %c in (*.log; *.js) do copy "%c" "d:\temp2"
```

Both file types should copy to the destination folder, but they don't.

Comment: What made you decide to use a semicolon, `(*.log; *.js)`, over say  `(*.log, *.js)`,  `(*.log *.js)`, doublequoted commas or spaces, `("*.log","*.js")`, `("*.log" "*.js")` and as your question is tagged [tag:batch-file] not [tag:cmd], using those with `%%c` instead of `%c`?

Comment: Thanks that worked. And regarding `%c` I just wasn't really aware how it properly worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with a comma: (please note I do not have lots of .js files to work with therefore i chose .bin and .txt)

```
C:\Windows\System32>for /r %1 in (*.bin,*.txt)  do dir /b %1
...
C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository

\netathr10x.inf_amd64_9ef98e989e52e32c\
eeprom_qca9377_1p1_NFA435_olpc_LE_2.bin
eeprom_qca9377_1p1_NFA435_olpc_LE_2.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathr10x.inf_amd64_9ef98e989e52e32c\
qca61x4_1_1_2.bin
qca61x4_1_1_2.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathr10x.inf_amd64_9ef98e989e52e32c\
qca61x4_2_2.bin
qca61x4_2_2.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathr10x.inf_amd64_9ef98e989e52e32c\
qca9377_2_0.bin
qca9377_2_0.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netr28ux.inf_amd64_d5996f2a9d9aa9e3\FW
_7662.bin
FW_7662.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netr28ux.inf_amd64_d5996f2a9d9aa9e3\Pa
tch_7662.bin
Patch_7662.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\Intel\Echo\m\cohort_echo.bin
cohort_echo.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\Intel\HwKws\ReleaseNotes.txt
ReleaseNotes.txt

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\Intel\sid\ubm.bin
ubm.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\MailContactsCalendarSync\LiveDomainList.txt
LiveDomainList.txt

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\restore\MachineGuid.txt
File Not Found

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\SecureBootUpdates\dbupdate.bin
dbupdate.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\SecureBootUpdates\dbxupdate.bin
dbxupdate.bin

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3\LMUD1N40.TXT
LMUD1N40.TXT

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3\LMUD1P40.TXT
LMUD1P40.TXT

C:\Windows\System32>dir /b C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\default.help.txt
default.help.txt
```

Comment: `for /r %1 in (*.bin,*.txt)  do dir /b %1` does not look correct to me, have you actually opened a Command Prompt window and entered `for /?` to find out how the command works?

Comment: Yes, I did do that and I actually typed in the command and you can see the output.  This is the part of for /? that describes /r:     FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
    statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
    specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
    assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
    will just enumerate the directory tree.

Comment: Well if it doesn't tell you not to, I shall; please don't use `1`, _(or any single digit)_ as the the `%variable`, it will certainly create issues or misunderstandings with any arguments.